# Adding data into new dimension of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

I have a numpy array of size 55 x 10 x 10, which represents 55 10 x 10 grayscale images. I'm trying to make them RGB by duplicating the 10 x 10 images 3 times.

From what I've understood, I first need to add a new dimension to house the duplicated data. I've done this using:

`array_4d = np.expand_dims(array_3d, 1)`,

so I now have a 55 x 1 x 10 x 10 array. How do I now duplicate the 10 x 10 images and add them back into this array?

Quick edit: In the end I want a 55 x 3 x 10 x 10 array

Comment: What about just simply creating a new empty array of shape 55x3x10x10 and setting the slice to each variable (eg. `array_4d[:,0,:,:] = img0`)?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a 55x10x10x3 shape instead of 55x3x10x10 shape? When creating a numpy array from a PIL.Image, RGB values are always last. Of course, there is purpose in keeping the RGB layers completely separate if you plan to use them individually as masks later.

Comment: @DavidTriphon I'm pretty sure I need it as 55x3x10x10, I want to feed the array into one of torchvision's pre-written image classification nets as training data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first create a 3d array of size 55x10x10

```
from matplotlib          import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
original_array = np.random.randint(10,255, (55,10,10))
print(original_array.shape)
>>>(55, 10, 10)
```

Visual of first image in array:

```
first_img = original_array[0,:,:]
print(first_img.shape)
plt.imshow(first_img, cmap='gray')
>>>(10, 10)
```

[image]

Now you can get your desired array in just **one single step**.

```
stacked_img = np.stack(3*(original_array,), axis=1)
print(stacked_img.shape)
>>>(55, 3, 10, 10)
```

Use `axis=-1` if you want channel last

Now let us **verify** that the value are correct by extracting the first image from this array and taking average of 3 channels:

```
new_img = stacked_img[0,:,:,:]
print(new_img.shape)
>>> (3, 10, 10)

new_img_mean = new_img.mean(axis=0)
print(new_img_mean.shape)
>>> (10, 10)

np.allclose(new_img_mean, first_img) # If this is True then the two arrays are same
>>> True
```

For **visual verification**, you'll have to move the channel to last because that is what `matplotlib` needs. This is a 3 channel image, so we are not using `cmap='gray'` here

```
print(np.moveaxis(new_img, 0, -1).shape)
plt.imshow(np.moveaxis(new_img, 0, -1))
>>> (10, 10, 3)
```

[image]